# Question About Graphics Card Driver Installation

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I'm really new to Ubuntu and really liking the help given on this site, i used quite a bit so far but I'm really confused as to how I should install graphics card drivers for my machine.

First off, I have an acer 3830TG, and the graphics card on it is Nvidia GT 540M.

If anyone can please point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. :)

I'm running 12.04.